# How can I include a map viewer into my web server from my ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, web, viewer

I have a web server, what contains my website. I would like to put a map viewer into my site, what would connected to my ArcGIS Server. How can I do this in the easiest way?
The ArcGIS Server and my web server are different servers.

Comment: so, is your problem about editing the website or is it a networking problem?

Comment: The question in its current state is too broad. You'll have to provide more details about your configuration to narrow down the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your problem is that your ArcGIS Server is not public facing but your web server is (and assuming you can't change this), then I see two relatively easy solutions:

1) Install ArcGIS Server Web Adaptor on your web server and point it at your ArcGIS Server.  Which would effectively open your AGS completely up to the web.  See ESRI explanation: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_the_ArcGIS_Web_Adaptor/01540000028p000000/

2) If you are slightly more savvy and/or are concerned about keeping your AGS as isolated as possible, you could use a proxy page on your web server to point back to the internal service.  See https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/ags_proxy.html.